# Problem on enabling desktop boot in raspi-config: error displayed

Tags: raspbian

I've just installed Raspbian in my Raspberry Pi 3. It starts in command line mode.

I want to configure desktop boot using raspi-config (option 3). however when I try to save the configuration an error is displayed saying it's not possible code error 1
startx is not found as command in the s.o

Comment: Did you install raspbian or raspbian lite?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you initially installed Raspbian Lite which does not come with a GUI by default. You at least need to install the package *xinit* (e.g. using `apt-get install xinit`) so that `raspi-config` can find `startx`.

But you very likely need to install more packages to get a usable GUI on Raspbian Lite, e.g. `apt-get install lxde`.

Answer (score 0):

For Raspbian Stretch Lite it shows you to install the package lightdm. Once you install it should work

sudo apt-get install lightdm